# Multiple Developers working on same add-in

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, 2016

How multiple developers can work on the same SharePoint add-in (both SharePoint hosted and provider hosted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host your code in any source control management system like TFS (onpremise or online), Bitbucket, github etc. This would allow multiple people to login and contribute to your code.